# Using batch file to enumerate through registry keys

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm trying to query the install location of an installed software. Each new version of it creates it's own key in the registry following this pattern:

```
HKLM\Software\MySoftware\<VERSION>
```

Example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\0.2.0]
"InstallDir"="C:\\Program Files\\MySoftware"
```

How can I query the `InstallDir` of the latest version installed on the computer?

Comment: And how the version looks like?Plain number? Does it have dots , underscores?

Comment: So far there are only numbers, 0.1.0 and 0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
regedit /e /s HKLM\Software\MySoftware C:\export.txt
set version_candidate=000

for /f "tokens=4,5,6 delims=\." %%a in ('type C:\export.txt ^|findstr /r "[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]"') do (
    if %%a%%b%%c gtr !version_candidate! set version_candidate=%%a%%b%%c

)

set version=%version_candidate:~0,1%.%version_candidate:~1,1%.%version_candidate:~2,1%
regedit /e /s HKLM\Software\MySoftware\version C:\export2.txt

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a do ('type C:\export2.txt ^|find /i "InstallDir"') do (
    set i_dir=%%a
)
echo %i_dir%
endlocal
```

Rather a guess as I can't know how your registry entries look like.